# requirements.txt/pip error when deploying a flask app using Vercel

Tags: python, flask, deployment, vercel

im trying to deploy a flask app on vercel and im getting this error:

Error: Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path1/requirements.txt
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==303 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==303

im running python 3.11.0

I tried commenting out those packages and deploying on the site but neither worked

here is the requirements.txt:

```
absl-py==1.4.0
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiohttp-retry==2.8.3
aiosignal==1.3.1
altair==4.2.2
asttokens==2.2.1
astunparse==1.6.3
async-generator==1.10
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==23.1.0
autopep8==2.0.2
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
blinker==1.6.2
Brotli==1.0.9
bs4==0.0.1
cachetools==5.3.0
certifi==2022.12.7
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
clear==2.0.0
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
colorgram.py==1.2.0
comm==0.1.3
contourpy==1.0.7
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.6.7
decorator==4.4.2
discord==2.2.2
discord.py==2.2.2
distro==1.8.0
entrypoints==0.4
exceptiongroup==1.1.1
executing==1.2.0
filelock==3.12.2
Flask==2.3.2
flatbuffers==23.5.26
fonttools==4.39.3
frozenlist==1.3.3
gast==0.4.0
gdown==4.7.1
gitdb==4.0.10
GitPython==3.1.31
google-api-core==2.11.1
google-api-python-client==2.94.0
google-auth==2.22.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==1.0.0
google-pasta==0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.59.1
grpcio==1.56.2
h11==0.14.0
h5py==3.9.0
httplib2==0.22.0
idna==3.4
imageio==2.31.1
imageio-ffmpeg==0.4.8
importlib-metadata==6.6.0
ipykernel==6.22.0
ipython==8.12.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
jedi==0.18.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.2.0
jupyter_client==8.1.0
jupyter_core==5.3.0
keras==2.13.1
kiwisolver==1.4.4
libclang==16.0.6
lightgbm==3.3.5
lxml==4.9.2
Markdown==3.4.4
markdown-it-py==2.2.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib==3.7.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
mdurl==0.1.2
moviepy==1.0.3
multidict==6.0.4
mutagen==1.46.0
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
networkx==3.1
numpy==1.24.2
oauthlib==3.2.2
openai==0.27.4
opencv-python==4.8.0.74
opt-einsum==3.3.0
outcome==1.2.0
packaging==23.0
pandas==2.0.0
parso==0.8.3
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==9.5.0
platformdirs==3.2.0
prettytable==3.7.0
proglog==0.1.10
prompt-toolkit==3.0.38
protobuf==3.20.3
psutil==5.9.4
pure-eval==0.2.2
pyarrow==11.0.0
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
PyBrain==0.3
pycodestyle==2.10.0
pycparser==2.21
pycryptodomex==3.18.0
pydeck==0.8.1b0
Pygments==2.14.0
PyJWT==2.7.0
Pympler==1.0.1
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyperclip==1.8.2
pyrsistent==0.19.3
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python-version==0.0.2
pytube==15.0.0
pytz==2023.3
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
pywin32==306
pyzmq==25.0.2
redis==4.5.5
requests==2.28.2
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rich==13.3.5
rsa==4.9
scikit-learn==1.2.2
scipy==1.10.1
selenium==4.10.0
six==1.16.0
smmap==5.0.0
sniffio==1.3.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.4.1
spotipy==2.23.0
stack-data==0.6.2
streamlit==1.22.0
tabula==1.0.5
tabula-py==2.7.0
tabulate==0.9.0
tenacity==8.2.2
tensorboard==2.13.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.1
tensorflow==2.13.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.13.0
tensorflow-intel==2.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.31.0
termcolor==2.3.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
toml==0.10.2
toolz==0.12.0
tornado==6.2
tqdm==4.65.0
traitlets==5.9.0
trio==0.22.0
trio-websocket==0.10.3
twilio==8.2.1
typing_extensions==4.5.0
tzdata==2023.3
tzlocal==4.3
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.15
validators==0.20.0
watchdog==3.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.6
webdriver-manager==3.8.6
websockets==11.0.3
Werkzeug==2.3.6
wrapt==1.15.0
wsproto==1.2.0
yarl==1.8.2
yt-dlp==2023.7.6
zipp==3.15.0
```

Comment: Please put the `requirements.txt` file in the question.

Comment: I see some inconsistencies in this question. You said "I'm running python 3.11.0", but you said you're invoking a binary called `python3.9`. You've also reported an error about `pywin32==303`, but the provided `requirements.txt` says `pywin32==306`. Can you please fix those? And also, please state which operating system you are using, as that can affect what `pip` serves back. "on Vercel" is not sufficient...are you deploying to Linux or Windows?